# The msiexec ignore the property values(commandline arguments) when installing app silently after advertising the package

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

The msiexec.exe ignore property values when installing the msi silently after advertising it.
This is my scenario. My windows service advertise the msi with the following code :

```
//Advertising the msi file
            Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = @"msiexec.exe",
                    Arguments = string.Format(@"/jm ""E:\MyApp.msi"""),
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false
                }
            };

            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

then, the service call a remote app to install the app with elevated privileges but the msiexec ignore any commandline options that i pass to the command:

```
Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = @"msiexec.exe",
                Arguments = string.Format(@"/i ""E:\MyApp.msi"" /q UPDATING_AUTOMATICALLY=1"),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            }
        };

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();`
```

**The UPDATING_AUTOMATICALLY=1 is ignored but i run the installer without being advertised first, all things are working correctly and the msiexec read them correctly**

Comment: Is that property declared secure="yes"?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand you, my custom property is UPDATING_AUTOMATICALLY=1

Comment: You are right! it works fine by setting secure="yes". You can solve the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may be that the property needs to be declared secure="yes".